# Cannot plot from files anymore after re-installing Miktex

Tags: tikz-pgf, miktex, texmaker, plot

I have recently re-installed Miktex and I cannot plot form a file anymore that compiled before re-installing it. The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw plot file{line.dat};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces the error message "File ended while scanning use of \pgf@parsexyline.\par". The file line.dat contains 2 lines

```
0.5660 0.6968
1.0000 0.6968
```

and no invisible characters. I checked that the --enable-write18 is added to the pdflatex command in TeXmaker and that the installation path of GNUplot is added to the PATH variable. I am at a complete loss because this example is so minimal, yet it still doesn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: show the log-file.

Comment: Link to the log file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18ALwzUBqGrJSuCjPYkicw-MjHnMsOM2j/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: I can reproduce your error if I change the line ending to CR, but only in miktex, in texlive it is okay.

Comment: Hmm, I get the error both when the line.dat file contains CR and CRLF end-of-line characters. Any ideas what might be causing it?

Comment: There is clearly a bug in miktex and I opened an issue https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/364. But it affects for me only files with CR-ending, so check carefully if you really changed the ending.